# Is definability in $(\mathbb{Q};*)$ minimal with respect to definability in $(\mathbb{Q}^{+};*)$?

Tags: model-theory

This is similar to a previous question I asked, here: [Is the structure $(\mathbb{R}, *)$ "weakly minimal" in this precise sense?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3915642/is-the-structure-mathbbr-weakly-minimal-in-this-precise-sense). Let $(\mathbb{Q};*)$ and $(\mathbb{Q}^{+};*)$ denote the structures consisting of the rational numbers with multiplication and the nonnegative rational numbers with multiplication, respectively. Is $(\mathbb{Q};*)$ minimal with respect to $(\mathbb{Q}^{+};*)$? This is what I mean by that question. Let $D$ denote the family of parameter definable sets in $(\mathbb{Q}^{+};*)$, and let $-D$ denote the additive inverses of the family of parameter definable sets in $(\mathbb{Q}^{+};*)$. Is every parameter definable set in $(\mathbb{Q};*)$ either finite, cofinite, a member of $D$ modulo a finite set, a member of $-D$ modulo a finite set, or the union of a member of $D$ and a member of $-D$, modulo a finite set? I would be very interested in a definable subset that is not either of these five cases. Also, as an additional bonus question, I would be interested in a definable subset that falls under the fifth case that is not of the form $d \cup -d$ modulo a finite set for some member $d \in D$, or a proof that there is none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Throughout, all definability/interpretability is first-order and **with** parameters.)*

Your guess is **correct** (and is more snappily stated as, "If $X$ is definable in the rationals with multiplication, then both $X\cap\mathbb{Q}^+$ and $\{q\in\mathbb{Q}^+:-q\in X\}$ are definable in the positive rationals with multiplication").

Let $\mathfrak{A}=(\mathbb{Q}^+;*),\mathfrak{B}=(\mathbb{Q};*)$. It turns out that $\mathfrak{A}$ interprets $\mathfrak{B}$ in a natural way using three parameters, say $2,3,4$: the domain of the interpretation is the set $$\{(2,a):a\in\mathbb{Q}\}\cup\{(3,a):a\in\mathbb{Q}\}\cup\{(4,4)\}\subseteq\mathfrak{A}^2,$$ with intuitively $(2,a)$ standing for $a$, $(3,a)$ standing for $-a$, and $(4,4)$ standing for $0$. This set, and the corresponding. multiplication rule, is definable in $\mathfrak{A}$ using the three parameters $2,3,4$. Call this interpretation $\Theta$.

Now given a definable set $D=\varphi^\mathfrak{B}$ in $\mathfrak{B}$ (without parameters for simplicity), we can use the interpretation above to define the positive and negative parts of $D$ in $\mathfrak{A}$. Specifically, to tell whether $a$ is in $D^+$ we ask whether $(2,a)$ satisfies $\varphi$ inside $\Theta$, and similarly to tell whether $a$ is in $D^-$ (= $-a\in D$) we ask whether $(3,a)$ satisfies $\varphi$ inside $\Theta$.

---

For the bonus question, consider the union of the following two definable sets:

- The set of all elements which do have square roots but do not have cube roots.
- The set of all nonzero $x$ such that $x$ has a cube root and $-x$ has a square root.

The first piece consists entirely of positive elements, the second consists entirely of negative elements, both pieces are infinite and coinfinite, and they are fully antisymmetric in the sense that no set of the form $\{z,-z\}$ is in their union.

Comment: What about the additional bonus question?

Comment: @user107952 See my edit.

Comment: I think there is a slight misunderstanding. I mean, I am looking for a definable subset that falls under the fifth case, but is not of that form. The fifth case is a definable subset that is the union of a member of $D$ and a member of $-D$. I want something like that, but is not of the form $d \cup -d$ modulo a finite set, for some member $d$ of $D$.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, would the set of rationals that have either a square root or a cube root satisfy my conditons?

Comment: @user107952 Ah, I misunderstood. Yes, your version would work. I've modified my example along different lines.